# Solr Data Import - array of strings

Tags: solr

Hi can anybody point me in the right direction for using Solr's Data Import Handler (DIH) to create an array of strings based on the SQL query.

My Solr DIH config looks like this:

```
  <dataConfig>
    <dataSource driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
       url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/data"
       user="xxxxx"
       password="xxxxxx" />
    <document>
      <entity name="item" query="select id, subject from table1">
        <field column="id" name="id" />
        <field column="subject" name="subject" />
        <entity name="ip_address" query="select ip_address from table2 where id='${item.id}'">
          <field column="ip_address" name="ip_address" />
      </entity>
     </entity>
    </document>
  </dataConfig>
```

The query on table2 actually returns multiple items so I need this to be reflected in my documents.

e.g. :

```
{
"numFound": 1,
"start": 0,
"docs": [
    {
        "id": "29331109",
        "subject": "Test document",
        "ip_address": [
            "88.103.210.139",
            "88.103.210.144",
            "88.103.210.133"
        ],
        "_version_": 1468439879154139100
    }
]
}
```

This is almost working for me except that Solr is only populating the first ip_address in my documents.

Here's the relevant part of my Schema:

```
 <!-- Custom Field names  -->

<field name="serial_number" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="subject" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="ip_address" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

Comment: Can you add schema, please?

Comment: Update to include schema!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is the "ip_address" field defined in schema.xml? It should be multiValued field.

Comment: Yes I have set it to a Multivalued field !

Comment: Just double checked this, deleted my entire core and reloaded it. Its working as expected now - thanks!